# How do I change the size of the text in a Tab?

Tags: android

I am trying to change the text size in a tab and also trying to create some space(padding) in the image from the top.

```
<style name="MineCustomTabText" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
<item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

and in my tablayout

```
app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MineCustomTabText"
```

But it doesn't work

Comment: bte, for next time.. **add some code please**. Add what you tried, what you failed, what you looked for and the code you are trying to edit. "_create some space in the image from the top_" means all and anything..

Answer (score 0):

you will find how there suggesting for using dimens.xml for different devices of android for Example see Below structure :

```
res/values/dimens.xml

res/values-small/dimens.xml

res/values-normal/dimens.xml

res/values-large/dimens.xml

res/values-xlarge/dimens.xml
for Example you have used below dimens.xml in values.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <dimen name="text_size">18sp</dimen>
</resources>
In other values folder you need to change values for your text size
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use the hard code value for `text size`. 
use it like the following

```
android:text-size="20sp"
```

for the image part use `paddings` see this [link]

(http://android4beginners.com/2013/07/lesson-2-2-how-to-use-margins-and-paddings-in-android-layout/)